# get record between two dates

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I want to fetch record where start_date is `01/01/2017` and to_date is `02/25/2018` problem is it cannot show id 2 record

date store in varchar MM/DD/YY

This is my query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `new_item` 
WHERE  `from_date` >= '01/01/2017'
  AND `to_date` <= '02/25/2018'
```

id 2 record not shown

```
  id   from_date     to_date
   1   01/01/2017    02/05/2018
   2   01/20/2017    06/20/2017
   3   02/05/2018    02/25/2018
   4   02/02/2018    02/20/2018
```

Comment: Just the ID 2 you want to hide?

Comment: i think this query shows all the record but it can show 3 records

Comment: Why isn't id 2 valid? both dates are between the from and to dates.

Comment: this is my problem @ypercube tells me the problem is in my date format because date store in varchar

Comment: Yes, and `'02' < '06'` (compared as texts. So  `'02/25/2018' < '06/20/2017'` (as texts). Because they are texts for the database. You told the database - when you created the table - that they are `VARCHAR`, which means text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem:**

> date store in varchar MM/DD/YY

That is your problem. You are storing dates in character columns. Even worse, in a non-aligned format.

**Solution:**

Use a type that suits your data. You are storing dates, use the **`DATE`** type.

Then you won't have to decide or worry about the internal format that dates are stored. You'll only have to provide date literals in a format that MySQL accepts (eg. ISO: `YYYY-MM-DD`). Your query would then work just fine:

```
SELECT * 
FROM new_item 
WHERE from_date >= '2017-01-01'
  AND   to_date <= '2018-02-25' ;
```

Comment: its mean my query is correct only problem is in my format

Comment: The problem is you used `VARCHAR` type for the date columns.

Comment: Great job its work

Comment: `DATE_FORMAT(...)` to _format_ dates when reading.